# ec2 aws não responde a aplicação instalada

Tags: amazon-aws, spring-boot, ip

Recentemente recebi uma `ec2` para subir uma aplicação de um cliente nela, a aplicação foi feita em `springboot` e até então não tive dificuldades em instalar o `postgres` e a aplicação como serviço (`graças ao script ant`), bom serviço funcionando e aplicação subiu observando pelo log na porta `8080`, porem quando coloco o ip externo da aws e tento acessar o `/health` ele não da sinal de vida, literalmente. Percebi que o IP não pinga, parece que nao está reconhecendo acesso externo, fiz um `curl` dentro da maquina com `127.0.0.1:8080/health` e o mesmo funciona, ou seja, não é a aplicação. Ainda falta alguma configuração no servidor para que ele externalize o acesso no ip fornecido e eu consiga acesso a aplicação?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa criar uma regra no Security Group para liberar a porta 8080 externamente, conforme a imagem abaixo:

[image: security group amazon ec2]